# SolrCore java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrcloud

I have encounter the a `FileNotFoundException` exception occasionally when indexing, it's not occur every time. Anyone have some clue? Here is the traceback:

```
2012-10-14 11:37:28,105 ERROR core.SolrCore - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/admin/run/deploy/solr/core_p_shard2/data/index/_cwo.fnm (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:216)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory.openInput(MMapDirectory.java:218)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory.openInput(NRTCachingDirectory.java:232)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene40.Lucene40FieldInfosReader.read(Lucene40FieldInfosReader.java:47)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentCoreReaders.<init>(SegmentCoreReaders.java:101)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.<init>(SegmentReader.java:55)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ReadersAndLiveDocs.getReader(ReadersAndLiveDocs.java:120)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.BufferedDeletesStream.applyDeletes(BufferedDeletesStream.java:267)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.applyAllDeletes(IndexWriter.java:2928)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.applyAllDeletes(DocumentsWriter.java:180)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.postUpdate(DocumentsWriter.java:310)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:386)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1430)
        at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:210)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:61)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:51)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:432)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:315)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:230)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:157)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:92)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1656)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:454)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:275)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

Except above exception, there is a auto commit error, here is detail

```
2012-10-15 01:37:10,722 ERROR update.CommitTracker - auto commit error...:java.io.FileNotFoundException: _5.fdt
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.fileLength(FSDirectory.java:266)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory.fileLength(NRTCachingDirectory.java:177)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfo.sizeInBytes(SegmentInfo.java:103)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.prepareFlushedSegment(IndexWriter.java:2126)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.publishFlushedSegment(DocumentsWriter.java:495)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.finishFlush(DocumentsWriter.java:474)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterFlushQueue$SegmentFlushTicket.publish(DocumentsWriterFlushQueue.java:201)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterFlushQueue.innerPurge(DocumentsWriterFlushQueue.java:119)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterFlushQueue.tryPurge(DocumentsWriterFlushQueue.java:148)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.doFlush(DocumentsWriter.java:435)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.flushAllThreads(DocumentsWriter.java:551)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.prepareCommit(IndexWriter.java:2657)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commitInternal(IndexWriter.java:2793)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commit(IndexWriter.java:2773)
        at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:531)
        at org.apache.solr.update.CommitTracker.run(CommitTracker.java:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

And  I have found that there lots of segment in index directory, and most of them is empty, like . totoal file number is 35314 in  index directory.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3n.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3o.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3o.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3p.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3p.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3q.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3q.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3r.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3r.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3s.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3s.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3t.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3t.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3u.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3u.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3v.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3v.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3w.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3w.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3x.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3x.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3y.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3y.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3z.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k3z.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k40.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k40.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k41.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k41.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k42.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin systems     0 Oct 14 11:37 _k42.fdx
```

Comment: Have you tried running [CheckIndex](http://solr.pl/en/2011/01/17/checkindex-for-the-rescue/) on your index?

Comment: crossposting ftw: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201210.mbox/%3CCAN4YXvfDHyLqN4-Nfa1wKdXBWh9mu0OqdfOMzpmH+38mv1otTA@mail.gmail.com%3E